# R RODBC Data Types and DB2

Tags: r, db2, odbc, rodbc

I'm using RODBC to connect to an external DB2 server ('DB2/AIX64'), and it isn't handling data types correctly.  Instead of taking the type used by DB2, it seems to be guessing based on the column contents.  This causes problems when there are columns stored as character on the DB2 server, but consist only of numeric values.  **Is there a way to correct this behavior in RODBC?  Failing that, is there a way to extract the DB2 types returned by the query programatically, so I can automatically convert the output myself?**

I can use the `as.is` option, but that returns almost everything as character, so I need to go back and do the conversions myself.  Since I'm working in a situation where I have dozens of different queries, doing this manually each time is unfeasible.

```
> library(RODBC)
> 
> sql_tst <- 'SELECT Tables.Tabschema,
>        Tables.Create_time,
>        Date (Tables.Create_time) AS Create_date,
>        Tables.Tableid,
>        Cols.Tbcreator,
>        Cols.Tbname,
>        Cols.Name,
>        Substr (Char (100 + Cols.Colno), 2, 2) AS Chr_colno   FROM    Sysibm.Syscolumns AS Cols
>        INNER JOIN
>           Syscat.Tables Tables
>        ON (Tables.Tabname = Cols.Tbname) AND
>           (Tables.Tabschema = Cols.Tbcreator) FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY   WITH UR'
> 
> channel <- odbcConnect(db, believeNRows=FALSE)
> 
> outtbl <- sqlQuery(channel, sql_tst)
> 
> close(channel)
> 
> str(outtbl)
```

Note that Chr_colno is returned as a numeric field in this example, not a character field like it should be.  If I use "as.is", Create_time and Create_date are returned as text fields, instead of date fields.

```
setSqlTypeInfo("DB2/AIX64", c(list(double="DOUBLE", integer="INTEGER", logical='VARCHAR(5)'), list(character="VARCHAR(255)")))
```

I experimented with `setSqlTypeInfo`, but it returned the error message

> "Error in typesR2DBMS[[driver]] <<- value[c("double", "integer", "character",  : 
>     cannot change value of locked binding for 'typesR2DBMS'"

Comment: See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-db/2015q1/001509.html). Let me know if you manage to get any feedback from certain parties on this. I have been steadfastly ignored for months now.

Comment: ...you might try using **RJDBC** instead, it might handle information sent from the db about column types more sensibly (I've never used it, though).

Comment: I can't install Java on my work machine, so RJDBC is a no-go.  I think modifying sqlGetResults somehow is my only option, so I'm researching how I do that.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/joranE/RODBC) for an example.

Comment: What information on columns is returned will depend on the db and the driver. For example I've confirmed that the fix I referenced above works with my drivers, but not on a coworkers Windows machine

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have the same problem.

Comment: I ended up writing a modified version of sqlGetResults that replaces this line --

if(is.numeric(data[[i]])) next

With this -- 

if(cData$type[i] %in% c("varchar","char") | is.numeric(data[[i]])) next

That seemed to work.  (Then I got irritated and switched to Python.)